# French to English Translation - Que

Tags: sens

Je ne peux pas comprendere le sens de « que » ici - aussi « gardes ponctuelles »

> Je cherche aussi bien ***des gardes ponctuelles*** ***qu'*** à la journée.

Quelle est le sens de « animatrice scientifique », « sein » et « populaire »

> Je suis actuellement ***animatrice scientifique*** au ***sein*** d'une association d'éducation ***populaire***.

Comment: Welcome to SE. There are quite a few formatting problems with your post. Please next time check the preview to make sure everything is in order before posting your question.

Comment: « Garde ponctuelle » : Work from time to time, on demand (no regular planning), according to needs. « Garde » may differ according to context: Baby-sitting, Shift (for doctors, etc.).  « Aussi bien... que » : just as well. So either « garde ponctuelle » or « day-time ». But could you give context (what kind of job)?

Comment: Il y a plusieurs questions posées ici. "que" dans la phrase donnée c'est une question. Il faut en poser une autre pour l'autre phrase en donnant les résultats de tes recherches sur les expressions pas comprises. French Language ne remplace pas la recherche préalable dans un dictionnaire [au sein de](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/au%20sein%20de) ou un outil comme wikipedia : [Éducation populaire](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89ducation_populaire)

Comment: Please only ask about one topic per post.

Answer (score 7):

> Je cherche aussi bien des gardes ponctuelles qu' à la journée.

Here, "aussi bien [...] que" could be translated as 'as well as' meaning she's looking for both of those things.

> Je suis actuellement animatrice scientifique au sein d'une association
>   d'éducation populaire.

- 'Animatrice scientifique' means 'Scientific animator', someone making activities related to science.
- 'Au sein' is a french expression, it means 'in','inside'.
- 'Populaire' can have two meanings depending on the context : 'famous/popular' or 'related to the people'.

Comment: You can't explain *populaire*  disconnected from *éducation* here. *L'"éducation populaire"* ("Popular education") is a concept, a social and political movement originating in the *Siècle des Lumières* (Enlightenment). There are quite a number of *associations d'éducation populaire* in France nowadays, mots of them local. As in *"Université populaire*" *populaire* here means "related//belonging to the people".

Comment: doesn't "Populaire" translate to "popular", simply ? Also, the whole expression "as well as" is actually replaced by "aussi bien ... que", not "que" alone.

Comment: @Laurent : Indeed "popular" is a valid translation, and maybe even easier to understand. And you are right fort "aussi bien que", I'm changing my answer.

Comment: Merci à tous.
C'était une publicité                                                                                                   BABY-SITTING, SOUTIEN SCOLAIRE

Bonjour,
Jeune femme de 25 ans, sérieuse et expérimentée, je vous propose de
garder vos enfants sur Antibes et ses environs. Je cherche aussi bien des
gardes ponctuelles qu'à la journée. Mes horaires sont souples et j'accepte
les urgences.
Je garde des enfants de tout âge depuis mes 16 ans et je suis
actuellement animatrice scientifique au sein d'une association
d'éducation populaire.

Comment: Glad we could help ! Make sure to tick my answer if you think the topic is closed, it will help people looking for this translation too.